# When MediaRecorder starts in Google Glass eye gestures are not detected anymore

Tags: google-gdk

I'm trying to create a app using GDK to record a video using MediaRecorder that uses eye gestures to control it (start rec, stop rec).  I'm able to use double blink to call MediaRecorder.start(), but from the moment MediaRecorder starts, I don't receive eye events anymore.

I used the code from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) as the base for the video recording logic and the code from [here](https://github.com/thorikawa/GlassEyeGestureDemo) for the eye gesture capture.

Below is the code that implements the listener to start/stop MediaRecorder:

```
class EyeGestureReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mAudioManager.playSoundEffect(Sounds.SUCCESS);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        String eyeGesture = extras.getString("gesture");
        boolean screenOff = extras.getBoolean("screen_off");

        Log.d(TAG, eyeGesture + " is detected");
        if (EyeGesture.DOUBLE_BLINK.toString().equals(eyeGesture)) {
            if (isRecording) {
                // stop recording and release camera
                ...
                isRecording = false;
            } else {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                // now you can start recording, startRecording will call MediaRecorder.start()
                if (startRecording()) {
                    isRecording = true;

                    // from this point I don't receive more eye events
                    // onReceive is never fired again.
                    // I've tested without calling mediaRecorder.start()
                    // and in this scenario eye events are detected without problems
                }
            }

        }  
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

On onCreate method of my main activity I instantiate them:

```
mEyeGestureManager = EyeGestureManager.from(this);
mReceiver = new EyeGestureReceiver();
```

And on onStart:

```
mEyeGestureManager.enableDetectorPersistently(EyeGesture.DOUBLE_BLINK, true);
mEyeGestureManager.enableDetectorPersistently(EyeGesture.WINK, true);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.google.glass.action.EYE_GESTURE");
filter.setPriority(2000);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EyeGesture stuff is not part of the GDK as it is not ready yet, thus bugs like this. Expect strange behaviour across the whole system if you use the,.